# Gradient and Hessian of function on matrix domain

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

Let $A \in R^{k \times p}$. Define $f(X) : R^{p \times k} \rightarrow R$ to be $f(X) = \log \det(XA + I_{p})$, where $I_{p}$ is a $p \times p$ identity matrix. I want to know what is the gradient and hessian of $f(X)$ with respect to $X$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(X)=\log(|\det(I+XA)|)$; we calculate $Df_X$ in a point $X$ s.t. $I+XA$ is invertible, that is, $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $XA$.

$Df_X:H\in M_{p,k}\rightarrow tr(HA(I+XA)^{-1})=tr((I+XA)^{-T}A^TH^T)$ or

$Df_X(H)=<(I+XA)^{-T}A^T,H>$ (the scalar product over the matrices). In other words, the gradient of $f$ is $\nabla(f)(X)=(I+XA)^{-T}A^T$, the lynn's result.

The Hessian is the bilinear symmetric function:

$Hess(f)(X):(H,K)\in M_{p,k}\times M_{p,k}\rightarrow -tr(HA(I+XA)^{-1}KA(I+XA)^{-1})$, that is equivalent to

$\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_{i,j}\partial x_{k,l}}=-tr(E_{i,j}A(I+XA)^{-1}E_{k,l}A(I+XA)^{-1})$ where $X=[x_{i,j}]$ and $E_{i,j}=e_ie_j^T$.

Comment: @ Wuchen , custom in this forum is to upvote the answers that you think are interesting; secondly, you accept (give the green chevron) the answer that you think is the best one.

Answer (score 3):

For convenience, define the matrix $M = (I+XA)$.

Now use the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) to write the function, differential and gradient as
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \log(\det(M)) \cr
   &= {\rm tr}(\log(M)) \cr\cr
df &= M^{-T}:dM \cr
   &= M^{-T}:dX\,A \cr
   &= M^{-T}A^T:dX \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= M^{-T}A^T \cr\cr\cr
}$$
Let's continue by taking the differential of the matrix gradient $G=M^{-T}A^T$
$$\eqalign{
 dG &= dM^{-T}A^T \cr
    &= -M^{-T}(dM^T)M^{-T}A^T \cr
    &= -M^{-T}(A^TdX^T)M^{-T}A^T \cr
    &= -B^T\,dX^T\,B^T \cr
} $$
where $B=AM^{-1}$

Define two $4^{th}$-order isotropic tensors $({\mathbb E}, {\mathbb W})$ with components
$$\eqalign{
  {\mathbb E}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl} \cr
  {\mathbb W}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{il}\delta_{jk} \cr
} $$
and use them to re-arrange the differential and find the Hessian ${\mathbb H}=\frac{\partial G}{\partial X}$ 
$$\eqalign{
 dG &= -(B^T\,{\mathbb E}\,B) : {\mathbb W} : dX \cr
 {\mathbb H} &= -(B^T\,{\mathbb E}\,B) : {\mathbb W}\cr
} $$
where the colon denotes the double-contraction (aka Frobenius) product.

Note that the Hessian is also a $4^{th}$-order tensor.

Comment: @ lynn , the equality $\log(\det(M))=tr(\log(M))$ is valid only if $I+XA$ has no $\leq 0$ eigenvalues. That implies that $\det(I+XA)>0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! But how could you get the Hessian? Even for an elmement of the Hessian?

Comment: If $\det(M)<0$ then $$\log(\det(M))= {\rm tr}(\log(M)) + \pi i$$ however the constant imaginary term is annihilated by differentiation.  So the rest of the derivation is correct.

Comment: @ hans , you are wrong. If $\det(M)<0$, then $M$ has a negative eigenvalue and (if $\log$ is the principal log) $\log(M)$ is not defined. You must choose another log and locally reason; it is easier not to use lynn's formula.